# ERROR: Documentación #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TABLE medicion ( ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

Quisiera saber como puedo relacionar dos llaves foraneas dentro de una misma tabla (TABLA MEDICIÓN) a diferentes tablas exteriores (Una tabla diferente por llave foránea, es decir a la tabla puntos y Personas).

CODIGO SQL (BASE DE DATOS):

```
CREATE DATABASE freatico;
USE freatico;
CREATE TABLE puntos (
    Id int(4) PRIMARY KEY not null UNIQUE,
    Localizacion text(35) not null,
    UltiMed float(5) not null, 
    Vreferencia float(5) not null, 
    AlTubo float(5) not null, 
    SMS varchar(60) not null
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci; 

CREATE TABLE personas (
    Nombre text(55) not null,
    CC int(40) PRIMARY KEY not null UNIQUE,
    Cargo text(55) not null,
    Telefono varchar(15) not null,
    Residencia varchar(60) not null,
    Nacionalidad text(50) not null
)

CREATE TABLE medicion (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idp int(4) not null,
    Nivel float(5) not null, 
    Hora time not null, 
    Fecha date not null, 
    CCP int(40) not null,
    SMS varchar(70) not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(idp) REFERENCES puntos(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(CCP) REFERENCES personas(CC)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre text(55) not null, 
    Apellido text(55) not null, 
    Username varchar(20) not null UNIQUE,
    Correo varchar(50)not null UNIQUE,
    Cargo text(50) not null,
    Password varchar(40) not null
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;
```

Comment: y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Como hago para relacionar las llaves foraneas de la tabla medicion correctamente a sus respectivas tablas

Comment: pero este codigo te tira algun error?

Comment: por supuesto que si

Comment: y cual es? no somos adivinos ;)

Comment: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TABLE medicion (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idp int(4) not' en la linea 10

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78326/discussion-between-angel-david-bermeo-and-gbianchi).

Comment: El error, debe ir en la pregunta.. mira [ask]

Comment: CCP no es del mismo tipo que CC en personas

Comment: Si es como te entiendo, pues hacer esto ID_disquera int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Disquera(ID_disquera),
ID_pais int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Paises(ID_pais), Pones el ID que ira en la tabla y con el FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE pones primero la tabla (Principal) y entre parentesis el id de la tabla principal

Comment: Amigo me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: que error? y despues de hacer que cosa?

Comment: Jumm. Pues ya cambie el tipo de dato que me dijo y volvi a cargar la base de datos y me aparece este error: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TABLE medicion (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idp int(4) not' en la linea 10

Comment: podrias dejar de lado los comentarios, y poner toda esta info en la pregunta (usa el boton [edit]), junto con el create cambiado?

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi me sirvio tu comentario

Comment: Si ejecutas los `CREATE TABLE` tal y como los tienes ahora claro que te dará error. Al crear la tabla `personas` **no terminas la sentencia por punto y coma `;`**  lo cual se traducirá en un error de sintaxis porque el manejador no entenderá que esa sentencia terminó y deberá pasar a crear la tabla `medicion`. Además, **no especificas el engine de la tabla `personas`**. Es posible que se cree como `MyIsam` (que es el engine por defecto) y posiblemente te dará error cuando intentes declarar relaciones entre esa tabla y otra con el engine `InnoDB`.